# react-redux обновляет одно из полей состояния самостоятельно без action

Tags: reactjs, redux

Всем добрый вечер. Есть условный код:

```
function Parent(){
 {routeMarkers} = useAppSelector((state) => state.mapSearch);
 return(
 <RouteMarkers routeMarkers={routeMarkers} />
 )
}
```

Cildren выглядит так:

```
export default function RouteMarkers({ routeMarkers }: { routeMarkers: Array<RouteMarkerType> }): JSX.Element[] {
  const newRouteMarkers: { current: Array<RouteMarkerType> } = useRef([]);
  const _routeMarkers = useRef(routeMarkers);

  _routeMarkers.current.forEach((marker, i, arr) => {
    const _marker = marker;
    const { pointId } = _marker;
    const markerIdBeforeHesh = pointId?.match(/^.*(?=#)/i)?.[0];
    const arrWithMarkerIdBeforeHesh = arr.filter(
      ({ pointId }) => pointId?.match(/^.*(?=#)/i)?.[0] === markerIdBeforeHesh,
    );
    if (arrWithMarkerIdBeforeHesh.length === 1) {
      _routeMarkers.current.splice(i, 1);
      newRouteMarkers.current.push({ ..._marker, place: 1 });
    }
  });

  return newRouteMarkers.current.map((routeMarker) => <RouteMarker {...routeMarker} key={routeMarker.pointId} />);
}
```

компонент получает массив с пропсами преобразует его и возвращает массив других компонентов.
После того как в поле стора добавляется элемент routeMarker компонент Parent отрисовывает этот маркер. Но при следующей отработке reduccer в него почему то передается состояние где поле routeMarkers уже пустой массив. При этом ни какие экшены связанные с этим поплем не отправлялись в reduccer.
Если переписать дочерний компонент вот так:

```
export default function RouteMarkers({ routeMarkers }: { routeMarkers: Array<RouteMarkerType> }): JSX.Element[] {
  return routeMarkers.current.map((routeMarker) => <RouteMarker {...routeMarker} key={routeMarker.pointId} />);
}
```

стор работает как и ожидается. Не могу понять в чем проблема. Прошу помощи.

Comment: Одно из предположений, что это происходит из-за `_routeMarkers.current.splice(i, 1);`. Хоть редюсер в react и отдает объект, по сути, это все тот же javaScript и идет передача ссылки на объект. Тут вы самостоятельно(в обход ваших экшенов) зануляете данные.

Comment: Огромное спасибо дорогой и глубокоуважаемый SwaD. Вы просто спасли мне жизнь. Кто бы мог подумать что Redux  допустит изменять состояние через изменение объекта ссылка на который тянется через несколько компонентов. В общем реши проблему скопировав routeMarkers через  Object.assign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**React-redux** реализует хранилище данных. Однако надо помнить о некоторых "фичах" поведения и его использования.

> react-redux возвращает *ссылку* на объект-состояние, а не клонированный объект.

Получая состояние, надо быть аккуратным с его использованием.

Если планируете манипулировать с полученными данными, склонируйте объект.
Допустим операторами spread, встроеными способами(**Object.assign()**) или с использованием внешних библиотек(lodash к примеру).

```
const { routeMarkers } = useAppSelector((state) => state.mapSearch);
const [ routeMark, setRouteMark ] = useState({});

useEffect(() => {
  setRouteMark({ ...routeMarkers });
}, [routeMarkers]);
```

Второй нюанс, заключается в том, что смена данных в хранилище может не вызвать событий **useEffect** в функциональных компонентах.

Для этого необходимо клонировать состояние перед возвратом в redux.
Изменить функцию возврата данных в хранилище **react-redux** с

```
const reducer = (
  state = { ...initialState },
  action: { type: string; payload: any }
) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'add':
      state.data = action.payload;
      return state;
    default:
      return state;
  }
```

На возврат склонированнных объектов. Если есть вложенные объекты, за которым так же может наблюдать **useEffect**, их тоже лучше склонировать.

```
const reducer = (
  state = { ...initialState },
  action: { type: string; payload: any }
) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'add':
      state.data = action.payload;
      return { ...state };
    default:
      return { ...state };
  }
```