# React + Redux. Обновляется хранилище (store), но не обновляется страница. Точнее обновляется, но только если сохранять файл компонента с connect

Tags: reactjs, redux

У меня ренедрится вот такой массив клеток, внутри которой или находиться звездочка, или клетка пустая (ещё она может быть закрашенная, но не суть):

```
    function GamePlayerZone(props) {
  
  return (
          <div className={classes.cells_field}>
            {props.cells.map((row, index) => (
              <React.Fragment key={index}>
                {row.map((cell, cellIndex) => (
                  <Cell status={cell}
                        onClickCell={props.onClickCell}
                        position={{x: index, y: cellIndex}}/>                        
                ))}

              </React.Fragment>
            ))}
          </div>
  );
}

export default GamePlayerZone;
```

Компонента Клетки:

```
    function Cell(props) {

  let onClickCell = () => {
    props.onClickCell(props.position);
  }

  let cell;
 
  if (props.status === "hited") {
    cell = <div className={classes.cell + " " + classes.hited}></div>
  } else if (props.status === "missed")  {
    cell = <div className={classes.cell}>*</div>
  } else if (props.status === "ship") {
    cell = <div className={classes.cell + " " + classes.ship}></div>
  } else {
    cell = <div className={classes.cell}></div>
  }

  return (
    <div onClick={onClickCell}>
        {cell}
    </div>
  ); 
}

export default Cell;
```

При нажатии на клетку в ней должна появиться звездочка, однако ничего не происходит. При этом функция onClickCell работает, редьюсер получает информацию и меняет стейт, но будто редакс или реакт не видит, что стейт изменился, и не обновляет страницу. *Самое удивительное, что все клетки, на которые я нажимал, заполняются звездочками, лишь когда я сохраняю файл, в котором прописаны mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps и connect (High Order Component), откуда я беру все данные из store*. То есть страница обновляется только при сохранении этого. Вот этот файл:

```
    function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    fieldPlayer: state.cellsPlayer,
    fieldEnemy: state.cellsEnemy,
    enemyName: state.enemyName
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    onClickCell: (position) => { 
      dispatch(clickCellActionCreator(position))
    }
  }
}

let GameWindowContainer = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(GameWindow);

export default GameWindowContainer;
```

Заранее спасибо! Вот если что компонента между контейнерной компоненты и компонентой, рендерящей массив клеток. Кстати, при сохранении файла с этим кодом ниже, страница тоже обновляется и все, что я нажимал до сохранения, вдруг появляется.

```
function GameWindow(props) {
  
  return (
        <div className={classes.game_window}>
          <GamePlayerZone cells={props.fieldPlayer} key={"playerZone"} playerName={"Вы"} onClickCell={props.onClickCell}/>
          <GamePlayerZone cells={props.fieldEnemy} key={"enemyZone"} playerName={props.enemyName} onClickCell={props.onClickCell}/>
        </div>
  );
}

export default GameWindow;
```

Comment: а что у вас в редусере происходит?

Comment: Посмотрите про [получение данных от redux](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1465644/1466192#1466192), может поможет в решении проблемы, возможно это как раз ваш случай с передачей в компонент ссылки